# Three questions about the group "reconstruction"

Tags: group-theory

Let a group $G$ is generated by its subset $S$, i.e. $G=\langle S\rangle$. Assume we also know how to express every element $g\in G$ as a word from the free group $F(S)$.

More precisely, let $\phi:F(S)\rightarrow G$ be the corresponding surjective homomorphism and $H=\{\phi^{-1}(g)|g\in G\}$. Then we suppose that the transversal is given, i.e. some set $X$ containing exactly one element from each set in $H$.

I am interested in the following three questions:

1. Can we reconstruct the group operation using this information, i.e. determine for each pair $a,b\in X$ another element $c\in X$ such that $ab=c$?
2. Can we at least say that the group is determined uniqely?
3. Does the uniqueness of a group following from some information imply the possibility of its total reconstruction?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. As for the last question, my thoughts are the following. If the group is finite, then the answer is yes. Indeed, if we know that there is a unique group with some property $P$, then we can systematically build finite groups and at some step we will stop at the group with the required property. The situation for the infinite case seems to me a bit unclear.

Comment: What information are you given for the questions you are asking? Can you be explicit with say question 1 (or even the others) in the finite group case?

Comment: @Paul thanks for the attention. I think the example given below by David Craven clarifies the situation. Actually, I didn't assume some extra information. In this case the answer to the first two questions is rather simply negative.

Comment: Okay, I was wondering since when I looked before there was only your comment on the answer saying it wasn't what you where looking for. So it was the case only $X$ was the given information. Also for the third question "uniqueness of a group" is true for any particular group (up to isomorphism) so not sure what that means.

Comment: @PaulPlummer In light of the answer below, I interpreted point 3 as: given a transversal $X$ (e.g. as a regular language over $S\cup S^{-1}$, or just as a finite set) for a group $G=F(S)/N$ *and* the knowledge that this transversal is a transversal for no other group, construct a presentation for $G$. This seems pretty subtle. For example, if $X$ contains one element then clearly $G$ is the trivial group, while in contrast it is undecidable whether a presentation defines the trivial group. This example also shows that, in general, $N$ is not the normal closure of the set $XX^{-1}$.

Comment: @user1729 I see the question now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking if there are two non-isomorphic groups with the same set of elements in the generators, i.e., the words in the generators expressing them are the same.

The answer to this question is trivially yes. Just take $S=G$. Then all words are $g_i$ for $g_i\in G$, so you can see none of the group operation at all from the transversal, all you obtain is the cardinality. In fact, only an upper bound for the cardinality because $g_i=g_j$ could be a relation. (Although since you take $S$ to be a subset of $G$ you should avoid this pitfall.)

It's also non-trivially yes. If $G$ has order $6$ then the group elements can be written $\{a,a^2,a^3,b,ab,a^2b\}$, and this is true for both $C_6$ and $S_3$.

If this is not the questiuon you are asking, then let me know what you meant, as I might have misunderstood.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think it is not exactly what I'm asking for. Suppose your group $G$ is generated by any of the possible subsets, say by some subset $S$. So you can express every element in $G$ as some word over $S$ and its inverses. Let these expressions form a set $X$. Show $X$ to your friend. Will he be able to define a group over $X$ that is isomorphic to $G$? If not, can he at least assert that (if you've done everything good) there exists exactly one appropriate group?

Comment: I show my friend $\{a,a^2,a^3,b,ab,a^2b\}$. What extra information am I giving him so that he knows that the group is $C_3\times C_2$ or $S_3$? Or do you want a transversal for *every* generating set?

Comment: I was writing a reply but suddenly noticed you've answered the question... Yes, it seems to clarify something. So the answer to my second (and hence the first) question is no.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking that I can cook up a transversal for every generating set for the groups of order $6$, simultaneously, that won't help you determine which one it is.

Comment: This is very nice. It generalises to all direct vs. semidirect products, unless I'm missing something, as they are always the same set under different operations: given transversals $A$ and $B$ of $F_1/N_1$ and $F_2/N_2$ respectively, then $AB$ is a transversal for $(F_1/N_1)\times (F_2/N_2)$ and also for $(F_1/N_1)\rtimes (F_2/N_2)$.

Comment: Indeed. But it gets worse than that. What if $\{a,a^2,b,ab\}$ is your set? Is your group cyclic or Klein four? (I'm always using $a^2$ rather than $1$ because I doin't know if the empty word is allowed, and anyway, it does not affect the answer.)